# Convert varchar(20) into date format Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a column months which is a varchar(20) . How can I convert it to a date format . I did try this

```
select CAST(month as DATE FORMAT'dd.mm.yyyy') from TABLE_123
```

For which I get an error invalid date supplied for TABLE_123.

Thank you.

```
month
12
11
1
3
6
6
```

Comment: Pretty hard to answer this without some sample data.

Comment: Do you have day and year columns as well?  You can't cast 12 as a date.

Comment: What day and year should be returned for a month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select CAST(month as DATE FORMAT'dd.mm.yyyy') from TABLE_123
```

According to my understanding the format of input string should be same as 'dd.mm.yyyy' while casting as date and your input sample shows that it does not satisfy that necessary condition.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.